# Drag ad drop images to make a customised gallery

Tags: views, rules, media

So I have a content type "Albums" which has a field "image". This allows a user to upload several pictures into this album.

What I have done next is made a view that displays all the different albums. So you see a thumbnail for each album.

Once you click on an album you are taken to the contents of that album. The content is basically a list of image fields with some other stuff like date published etc...

What I want to do now is being able to pick a picture from this album and drag it to like some sort of panel at the bottom and drop it there, then navigate around the website dragging and dropping different pictures from different albums.

Once you have finished with the selection there should be a button called "create" or something similar which will maybe call a script through some trigger which will zip the pictures and download them to your pc.

I have no idea how to do this. Help!

Thanks!

I'm using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a nice idea but probably not so easy to implement.

jQuery UI could help you with the drag and drop features. http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/
Drupalgardens does some galerie configuration through drag n drop - so there you may be able to get some inspirations on this. Especially since you can export the site and then look how exacly they do it. http://drupalgardens.com

Comment: Drupal garden has ended on 1st of August 2016.